# List executables in path on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

On Windows, how can I list which executables are in my path?

Comment: Type `where *.exe` at the command prompt.  Hard to see the point of that...

Comment: @HansPassant: Whatever the point may be, yours seems to be the answer! I never knew about `where` before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
where *.exe
```

for any other executable you should change the extension, such as .bat, .run. But there is a point here, `where` also searches the current directory, so if you want only the executables in $PATH, you should run it in an empty directory or exclude the results by hand or script.

Comment: Did you figure this out after seeing Hans's comment?

Comment: No, I was afk for a minute to take coffee, so i figured that he is asking for $PATH, not for any other path.

Comment: Well, if Hans is happy with your answer, I'm happy too. :)

Comment: If Hans is happy, everyone is happy! :)